# looking for .Net color dialog dropdown

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu, colordialog

I want something like the properties' color drop down in Visual Studio. I can't seem to find any tools for this though.

Comment: For which platform? Winforms? Web Forms? WPF? MVC? ...

Comment: Windows form. Desktop application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you won't find that "natively" on .NET. The PropertyGrid control displays its values based on Editors classes specifically designed for presenting/editing each property type in its own manner inside of it, and that's not what you need. Besides this, you will only find the [ColorDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.colordialog.aspx), which is not what you want - I guess.

You will need to get and reference a custom control from what is available on the web.
Here are some free options I've found on a quick search:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1484/NET-Color-Picker-Controls
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8305/The-ColorPicker-WinForms-Control-Revisited

PS: If you are working on a commercial app that demands a lot from the UI, you should consider [buying a full control/component set for Winforms](https://www.google.com/search?q=.NET%20winforms%20controls&oq=.NET%20winforms%20controls&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sugexp=les;cqn,fixedpos=false,boost_normal=40,boost_high=40,cconf=1.2,min_length=2,rate_low=0.035,rate_high=0.035,second_pass=false,ignore_bad_origquery=true&gs_nf=1&cp=22&tok=WaXiHKO44Bfad-U0wjrwmw&pq=.net%20winforms%20controls&gs_id=1&xhr=t&q=.NET%20winforms%20controls&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=.NET%20winforms%20controls&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=190c66b37009a7&biw=1440&bih=802), which brings a lot of nice controls (ColorPicker is one of them). From my own experience, it is worth.